# Why is Visual Studio generating this code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I have extended the `ComboBox` object, and I would like to assign values to it.

The values will be the same every time, and are not allowed to be changed at runtime.

Here is my object:

```
public class TimesComboBox: ComboBox
{
    //These items' values are copied from PARC View
    private readonly Dictionary<String, TimeSpan> CONSTANTS = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>()
    {
        {"3 H", new TimeSpan(0,3,0,0,0)},
        {"8 H", new TimeSpan(0,8,0,0,0)},
        {"12 H", new TimeSpan(0,12,0,0,0)},
        {"1 D", new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0,0)},
        {"3 D", new TimeSpan(3,0,0,0,0)},
        {"7 D", new TimeSpan(7,0,0,0,0)},
        {"30 D", new TimeSpan(30,0,0,0,0)}
    };

    public TimesComboBox()
        : base()
    {
        DataSource = CONSTANTS.Keys.ToList();
    }
```

When I run the code, the program throws the error:

```
Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.
```

And points me to the designer of the form where I am using the TimesComboBox:

```
// 
// timesComboBox1
// 
this.timesComboBox1.DataSource = ((object)(resources.GetObject("timesComboBox1.DataSource")));
this.timesComboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.timesComboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
"3 H",
"8 H",
"12 H",
"1 D",
"3 D",
"7 D",
"30 D"});
this.timesComboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 55);
this.timesComboBox1.Name = "timesComboBox1";
this.timesComboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
this.timesComboBox1.TabIndex = 63;
```

---

It looks to me like the designer is generating code that is trying to add the items twice.  Why is it doing this?  I thought that list would only be assigned to the DataSource at runtime, so why is Visual Studio be generating code before that?

Comment: Probably, those items were in the combobox when you saved.  You can either remove them using the property manager in Visual Studio, or you can simply delete the `AddRange` code from the Designer.

Comment: I read that it is bad to modify the designer code since it is auto-generated; this is an exception I guess?

Comment: Removing them using the Property Manager will have the same effect.  It's a round-trip tool, so if you delete the code from the designer, the entries will disappear from the Property Manager.

Comment: It seems the problems re-occurs every time I add a TimesComboBox to a new form; so I have to go into the designer of every form which I add a TimesComboBox to and remove the generated code.

Comment: Really?  You need to save the TimesComboBox in a state where the Items collection is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the constructor of your control class also runs at design time.  Which sets the DataSource *and* the Items properties, their values will be serialized like properties normally are.  So you see them back in the Designer.cs code.  Usually unseen, not when it generates an exception like it does in this case.

You tell the designer serializer to not do this by using the [DesignerSerializationVisibility] attribute:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public new ObjectCollection Items {
    get { return base.Items; }
}
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public new object DataSource {
    get { return base.DataSource; }
    set { base.DataSource = value;  }
}
```

Adding the [Browsable(false)] attribute also hides the property in the Properties window, very likely you'll want that as well.